# performance fix: join -t, -j99 file2 file1 | awk -F, -v OFS=, '$3==$6 && $4==$8 {print $2,$3,$4,$5,$7,$9}'

Tags: join, awk

File1

```
111,222,560,0.7
111,333,560,0.2
111,444,560,0.1
```

File2

```
2017,111,560,0.0537
2018,111,560,0.0296
2019,111,560,0.0624
```

output:

```
2017,111,560,0.0537,222,0.7
2017,111,560,0.0537,333,0.2
2017,111,560,0.0537,444,0.1
2018,111,560,0.0296,222,0.7
2018,111,560,0.0296,333,0.2
2018,111,560,0.0296,444,0.1
2019,111,560,0.0624,222,0.7
2019,111,560,0.0624,333,0.2
2019,111,560,0.0624,444,0.1
```

for file1 i have 31,000 lines
for file2 i have 1.3Million lines

and it it taking a really long time to process the file.
this command is running in unix

can anyone help? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 join -t, -1 2 -2 1 file2 file1  | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $2, $1, $3, $4, $5, $7}'
```

The result are the same but it should be faster.

Comment: With GNU join: `join -t, -1 2 -2 1 file2 file1 -o 1.1,1.2,2.3,1.4,2.2,2.4`

Comment: that "-1 2 -2 1" mean column 2 from file 1 and column 1 from file 2 will determine the join

Answer (score 0):

another `awk/join`

```
$ join -t, <(awk -F, '{print $2"_"$3 FS $0}' f2 | sort) \
           <(awk -F, '{print $1"_"$3 FS $2 FS $4}' f1 | sort) | cut -d, -f2-

2017,111,560,0.0537,222,0.7
2017,111,560,0.0537,333,0.2
2017,111,560,0.0537,444,0.1
2018,111,560,0.0296,222,0.7
2018,111,560,0.0296,333,0.2
2018,111,560,0.0296,444,0.1
2019,111,560,0.0624,222,0.7
2019,111,560,0.0624,333,0.2
2019,111,560,0.0624,444,0.1
```